# Spark Executor Peak JVM Memory onHeap Issue

Tags: spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

Executor pod is assigned with 9g Memory , Even after data processing is done executor still holds 3GB of JVM OnHeapMemory.

How to check which process is holding the memory after load is stopped ?

`kubectl top <pod_name>` gives whole node memory processes instead of pod memory .

[image]

config("spark.cleaner.periodicGC.interval","5min")
GC is configured to run for every 5 min , but doesn't seem to be clearing the memory

Comment: You're looking at peak memory, not at the current memory usage

Comment: When load is high its increasing upto 8GB , but no load is running and etl is stale also this memory is not reducing . (When executor  is created initially this Peak JVM MemoryonHeap is not occupied )